# Why is it allowed to have a container of an abstract class as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, abstract-class

Recently in our code base we have found a function that didn't compile in one specific compiler.

The scenario was something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Base{
    public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base(Base&&) = default;
    Base &operator=(const Base&) = default;
    Base &operator=(Base&&) = default;
    virtual void Method() = 0;
    int m_data{0};
};

class Derived : public Base{
    public:
    void Method() override{}
};


void func(std::vector<Base> &vec){
    int var = vec[0].m_data;//this compiles
    //auto base = vec[0]; //this does not compile
}

int main(){}
```

Why does this code compile? Given that `Base` is an abstract class, I wouldn't expect it to be allowed to create a container holding `Base` instead of `Base*` (or `std::unique_ptr<Base>` or ...). I am assuming, then, that the template `std::vector<Base>` is not instantiated on the function definition. When would it be instantiated then?

Comment: It'll fail if you try to put elements in it, but other than that, I don't think there's anything preventing you from creating an empty vector of an abstract class - `int var = vec[0].m_data;//this compiles` has UB since there can't be an element there.

Comment: You haven't created any vector yet, just told the compiler that you might have a reference to one.

Comment: You rather should use something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`, or at least `std::vector<std::ref<Base>>`

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract base class.  That is why `Base base;` fails.

Comment: @BoP even if the function parameter is passed by value, and not by reference the code still compiles. And that is precisely my question: how does it compile, since trying to instantiate the template `std::vector<Base>` isn't allowed?

Comment: @orlandini but Ted Lyngmo already explained that you can create empty such vector and take reference of it. Also you can std::move its value into other such vector or function argument. Your posted code besides undefined behavior of accessing first element is OK. It is nonsensical but nonsense can be expressed in every useful language in endless ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a vector of an abstract class. You just cannot populate it with elements. All the methods that do not require having an actual object of type Base still work: size, empty, begin, end, ...

There is nothing wrong with instantiating a template with a type that prevents some operations from working. The compiler is not in the business of telling you "oh no, all the important operations are disabled, so you better not try this". It generally cannot know which ones are disabled until you actually try to use them anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess what is still not really clear to me is how can you create a vector of an abstract class, but you are not allowed to explicitly instantiate its template.

It is my understanding that in the explicit instantiation the definition is actually formed. However, I thought the same would happen when declaring an instance of such template class.

Comment: @orlandini When you explicitly instantiate a class template, you instantiate *all* of its members, and in our case some of those cannot be instantiated with an abstract class (like push_back for example). When you declare a variable however, you just instantiate the constructor and the data members, and those are OK.

Comment: Thank you! That's quite interesting behaviour. Would you mind pointing me somewhere where I could read more about it?

Comment: It's all in the standard and in any good book that covers templates in depth. I have no specific source where I got it from but you can find it e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)